# SQL Server stored procedure allows to insert into a table only numbers, not characters

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I developed a vb.net application which connects to a SQL Server 2014. At server side I created the following stored procedure to insert a row to a table when called out by vb app.

```
create procedure uspInsertToTableWith1Value
@table nvarchar(50),
@column nvarchar(50),
@value nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @SQL nvarchar(50)
select @SQL = N'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@table) + ' (' + @column + ') ' + 'VALUES (' + @value + ')';
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

The vb app has a button with the following code:

```
Private Sub Button22_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button22.Click
Dim tbl1 = "Facility"
Dim cln1 = "f1"
Dim vl1 = TextBox7.Text
InsertToTableWith1Value(tbl1, cln1, vl1)
end sub
```

And this is the sub which connects to SQL Server:

```
Public Sub InsertToTableWith1Value(tbl, cln, vl)
    Try
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandText = "uspInsertToTableWith1Value"
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        With cmd.Parameters

            .AddWithValue("@table", tbl)
            .AddWithValue("@column", cln)
            .AddWithValue("@value", vl)
        End With
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        con.Close()
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

The problem is that when I add a new record to the table through the vb app it accepts only numbers. When I add characters or numbers with characters it cuts away all the head numbers leaving just the remaining characters and giving two Exception error, depending what I typed. For example if I type "2ww" I'll get "Incorrect syntax near 'ww'". If I type "ww" I'll get "Invalid column name 'ww'".

Any idea how to fix that? I already spent two days searching the net. Thanks to everybody who will help me.

Btw, if I add the row manually and directly through the server it accepts everything, which is ok.

I followed all the advice you guys gave me so this is my final code which works fine:
(I really hope to have posted this last phrase in the right place)

```
Public Sub InsertToTableWith1Value(tbl, cln, vl)
    Try
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
        cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT [" & tbl & "] (" & cln & ") VALUES ('" & vl & "')", con)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("@table", tbl)
            .AddWithValue("@column", cln)
            .AddWithValue("@value", vl)
        End With
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        con.Close()
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: **Why** does that stored procedure even exist? It's like you're trying to avoid SQL by re-implementing SQL, badly. If you're going to allow the application to have full access to insert data into any column in any table, just let it run ad-hoc `INSERT`s and be done with it.

Comment: Well, you are right, but since I'm new with SQL Server, I created this stored procedure just for my learning purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you need apostrophes around words

```
insert into table (col1) values ('2ww')
```

You can use '' to represent a single apostrophe in SQL Server.

A fix would be

```
select @SQL = N'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@table) + ' (' + @column + ') ' + 'VALUES (''' + @value + ''')';
```

**Edit** Note that this will only let you insert data into columns with a textual datatype, you don't want appostrophes for numeric data inserts.

Comment: SQL Injection alert! SQL Injection alert!

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed, just for textual datatype.

Comment: why not use sp_executesql with parameters ?

Comment: @Horia I agree but FYI you can't parameterize table/column names.